# google drive pagination not working. Getting Call to a member function getNextPageToken()

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have around 800 files on the drive. But I'm getting Call to a member function getNextPageToken() . I can get all files if I set the pageSize to higher. I wanna show 20 per page. How can i get it.

```
    'fields'  => 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents), nextPageToken',
```

$files->getNextPageToken();

Answer (score 0):

### You can use the optional parameter `pageSize`

Sample:

```
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 20,
  'fields' => 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents), nextPageToken'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

Please refer also to the [PHP quickstart for Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php).

### UPDATE: How to iterate through all pages with `nextPageToken`

```
var files = []
var nextToken;
gapi.client.drive.files.list({ 
    'pageSize': 20,
    'fields' => 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents), nextPageToken'
}).then(function(response) {
    nextToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
    files.push(...response.result.files)
    while (nextToken) {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'nextPage': nextToken,  
            'pageSize': 20,
             'fields' => 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents), nextPageToken'
        }).then(function(response) {
            nextToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
            files.push(...response.result.files)
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: according your code i can show only 20 but i want to show every page 20. My files are 800. Like i wanna send some limit to this function so that can i get each page 20.

Comment: According to my code each page will have 20 entries (as you requested), but with `nextPageToken` you can retrieve as many pages as you want - or until the results finish.  However, you need to implement a loop to iterate through all the pages. I will update my answer and provide a sample.

Comment: Thanks Ziganotschka. I have written the code like as below with $sercvice. Could you help me with this code how can i get with below code
$res = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);$data = array_merge($data, $res->getFiles()); foreach($data as $val){ $id[]= $file->getId(); .....}